# Loading a new view doesn't change the URL and and user can resend data under CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-post, codeigniter-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keep browser from resending post variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958590/keep-browser-from-resending-post-variables)

When I try to load a view after some processing is done, the URL doesn't change and If user accidentally refresh the page he will resend the request and it will be processed all again.

I load a view and I pass some data to it. So I can't use redirect. How can I solve this problem?

```
    $data['message'] = 'value1';
    $data['another_message'] = 'value2';
    $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

Comment: Please paste your code!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @tereško Thanks for your time. In those answers it is mentioned to redirect but as I stated before I can't use redirect() because I want to pass some data to the view.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Thanks, but It's a bit long. I edited my Question and added how I load the view.

Comment: @Zim3r - this is not enough to see what's going on, at all.

Comment: *fun fact*: you can use `$_SESSION` to store the data between requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168) for this.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't use this. first of all because I want to load a view instead of using redirect.